# Prevent angular directive from compiling more than once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that I manually render once:

```
let html = '<div>'
let scope = $rootScope.$new(true)
scope.foo = 42

let element = $compile(html)($scope)
element.appendTo(container)
```

After that, I don't want it to ever re-render, even if there is a $digest on the $rootScope. Is that possible with Angular?

Comment: what do you mean by re render.? could you add more code..with more explaination

Comment: Any progress on this? Could you share some more details of what you want exactly? I attempted to answer but feedback will definitely help us find the correct solution for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you wish to remove all bindings on your directive, you can call `$destroy` to remove any bindings on you have. Consider this example, where both directives bind `message`

```
<input ng-model="message" id="dirA" dir-a />
<input ng-model="message" id="dirB" dir-b />
<input ng-model="message" />
```

---

```
app.directive('dirA', [function () {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }
}]);

app.directive('dirB', [function () {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }
}]);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.message = 'hello'

    $timeout(function(){
        // destroy scope for dirA
        angular.element(document.getElementById('dirA')).scope().$destroy()
    })
}]);
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gdxuuc0v/)

Comment: thanks sal! i ended up not using angular at all for what i needed, because the initial compile was too slow (i was compiling ~200 directives @1ms/$compile and 1ms/$link).